# How can I suppress 'None' output from yaml.dump, in Python?

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, data-structures, yaml

I have a (simplified) class that prints its structure out, without further need to *reload* the object (`yaml.load` will not be used).

Is there a quick way to suppress `None` output (including variables set to `None`)? Perhaps `yaml.representer` can be used in some way.

```
import yaml

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = None
        self.b = [1,2,3]

    def __repr__(self):
        return yaml.dump(self)

A()
```

outputs

```
!!python/object:__main__.A
a: null
b: [1, 2, 3]
```

whereas I need:

```
!!python/object:__main__.A
b: [1, 2, 3]
```

This post is still active. I seek neat/robust ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by subclassing `YAMLObject` and defining the `to_yaml` class method.  For your particular example:

```
import yaml

class A(yaml.YAMLObject):
    yaml_tag = u'!A'

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = None
        self.b = [1, 2, 3]

    def __repr__(self):
        return yaml.dump(self)

    @classmethod
    def to_yaml(cls, dumper, data):
        cleaned_data = dict((k, v) for (k, v) in data.__dict__.items() if v is not None)
        return dumper.represent_mapping(cls.yaml_tag, cleaned_data)
```

The above class method skips any values that are `None`, given us only the instance values that we want.  Then when we use it, we get the output we expect:

```
>> print yaml.dump(A())
!A
b: [1, 2, 3]
```

Documentation on subclassing `YAMLObject`: http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation#YAMLObject

Documentation on the yaml `Dumper`:
http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation#Dumper

Comment: If my objects inherit class `yaml.YAMLObject`, would they have significantly larger memory footprint? Any rough measure of performance/memory drawbacks? FYI: I may have hundreds of sub-class instances...

Comment: I'm not sure about the memory footprint of subclassing the class.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The following would be a crude technique by casting the dumped output to a string and then formatting, but you can abstract it away nicely in a method:

```
>>> A()
!!python/object:__main__.A
a: null
b: [1, 2, 3]

>>> test = A()
test_string = str(test)
test_split = test_string.split("\n")

>>> test_split
['!!python/object:__main__.A', 'a: null', 'b: [1, 2, 3]', '']

>>> print test_split[0] + "\n" + test_split[2] + "\n"
!!python/object:__main__.A
b: [1, 2, 3]
```

You can tuck this into your **repr** function. Another standard library solution, last one I think for me, good luck:

```
import yaml

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = None
        self.b = [1,2,3]
        self.c = None
        self.d = 'wheee'

    def __repr__(self):
        string = re.sub(r'.*: null', '',str(yaml.dump(self)))
        string_split = string.split('\n')
        lines = [line for line in string_split if line.strip() != '']
        return '\n'.join(map(str, lines))
```

In which case, we still get the expected result:

```
!!python/object:__main__.A
b: [1, 2, 3]
d: wheee
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a quick way to automate this?

Comment: I alluded to abstracting it away, I've updated the code with one possible solution.

Comment: Thanks. I did figure out abstraction :) I'm just not sure how to design it so that it's clean and not messy for `yaml.dump` output of any complexity.